# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified error

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to a database using cx_Oracle in Python.
this is the way I'm doing it :

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user", "pass", "service")
```

I am able to connect to the db using sql developer with the same credentials but when I try to connect from python it throws the error :

> **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
>   specified**.

I tried the same thing from another system and I am able to connect to the database using `cx_Oracle`. The contents of TNSNames.ora file are exactly the same in both systems.

I removed everything and installed again hoping to get rid of mistakes I might have done the first time but I am still facing the same error.

Please let me know if there is any way to fix this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what was going wrong. 
The database uses a **LDAP** file. And in the SQLNET.ORA file, LDAP was not mentioned, that caused the error for me. 
Just adding **LDAP** to **NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH** in **SQLNET.ORA** solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with EZ connect instead, or you can use `cx_Oracle.makedsn()` to build up the connect string. If you provide the contents of your tnsnames.ora file I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: I tried using  
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost','port',service_name='service_name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='user_name',password='password',dsn = dsn_tns) but I still got the same error.

the parameters used in makedsn are from tnsnames.ora file.